# How do I build a query that returns the data from the previous business day in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a query in SQL that returns the data I need from the previous business day. The code runs five days a week, Monday-Friday.

What code do I write that would return Fridays data if the code is running on a Monday?

Note: I'm new so please tell me exactly where to put what code, Thanks

Currently my code functions so that on Tuesday, Ill get Mondays data; on Friday I get Thursdays Data, etc. On Monday, however, my code returns Sundays data (which is empty).

```
SELECT Distinct
[Entry Date]

FROM 
myTable


WHERE 

[entry date] >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) AND
[entry date] < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?'

Comment: I believe Cinchy

Comment: @coery . . . Your syntax is SQL Server (or Sybase).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can handle your problem by using if-else structure like below:

```
IF(DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())=1)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM  myTable
    WHERE [entry date] >= dateadd(day,-3,GETDATE())
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM  myTable
    WHERE [entry date] >= dateadd(day,-1,GETDATE())
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as a single query:

```
SELECT Distinct t.[Entry Date]
FROM myTable t CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddd', 'en-us') = 'Mon' THEN -3
                   ELSE -1
              END)
     ) v(offset)
WHERE [entry date] >= DATEADD(DAY, offset, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AND
      [entry date] < DATEADD(DAY, offset + 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));
```

The use of `FORMAT()` with a culture specifier is so the code works with any internationalization settings.  There are no underlying assumptions about when weeks start.

The transformations on `GETDATE()` are sargable ("index-safe") so the code can take advantage of an available index as well.

Comment: Thanks but it seems i dont have some of those keywords such as ELSE and END

Comment: @corey . . . `case` expressions are a pretty fundamental part of SQL.

Comment: Appreciate the help. When i copy your code exactly (Adding an end bracket after the word 'offset' and changing myTable to my actual table) I get this Error:
Unsupported Table Reference Type Encountered - Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.InlineDerivedTable